# Lego Model Renders Pink

Tags: rendering

After exporting an ldraw file from stud.io into blender through TonyLobster's ldraw importer, I went to try to render. It keeps rendering while tinted pink and I cannot figure out why. I know that the pink tint has to do with missing textures, but (that I know of) the importer I used should be getting the textures from the Ldraw parts library that I linked it to. I am using Blender version 2.79.

Comment: *"importer I used should be getting the textures from the Ldraw parts library"* check what Blender can actually find in material options or in File > External Data > Report Missing Files. Material options depend on engine which isn't indicated in your question. Other than that pink is missing texture (material, enviroment etc)